# I need to link comments to single post in django , i have no idea what to do , i'm self taught

Tags: python, django, django-views

i need crucial help, i need to link comments to single post in django , i have no idea  what to do

my **models**
i think this is the only part that i know what is goin on

```
from tkinter import CASCADE, Widget
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='User')
    text = models.TextField (max_length=200)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
    

class Comment(models.Model):#comment for the requests
    request = models.ForeignKey('sunu_app.Post', on_delete =models.CASCADE , related_name='comments', null=True , blank=True)
    # name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=True , blank=True)
    text = models.TextField ()
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

my views
i honestly had no idea what was going on there

```
# from typing_extensions import Self
from urllib.request import Request
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import *
from .models import *

def home(request):
    requests = Post.objects.all().order_by('-posted')
    count = Post.objects.all().count()
    #diplay the comments here and let it save in commentform.view
    comments = Post.comment_set.all()
    
    context = {'requests':requests , 'count':count , 'comments':comments}
    return render(request,'sunu_app/home.html', context)
    # context = {'cases':rooms} the second value is the data
    # you want to pass the first value is what it should be called in the template

def requestform (request):
    form = RequestForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    context = {'requestform':form}
    return render(request,'sunu_app/RequestForm.html',context)  

def deleteall(request):
    requests = Post.objects.all()
    requests.delete()
    return render(request,'sunu_app/home.html')

def commentform(request ,post_id):
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    requests = Post.objects.get(id = post_id)
    #save the comments here and let it display in home.view
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = Comment.objects.create{
            request = requests,
        }
        #pls i have no single idea what is goin on here
    
    context = {"commentform":form}
    return render(request,'sunu_app/CommentForm.html',context)
```

my home.html
i also have no idea what is goin on here

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    {%extends 'main.html'%}
    {% block content%}   
    <!-- <style>
        .home-container{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
        }
    </style> -->
    <!-- put everything in a freaking div -->
       
        <div class="addrequest">
            <a href="{% url 'requestform'  %}">
                <h3>Add request</h3>
            </a>
            <a href="{% url 'deleteall' %}">
                delete all Requests
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="intronote">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi hic maiores
                quisquam sed ipsa incidunt iste, minima aperiam est sunt
                nobis, soluta adipisci laborum esse. Placeat praesentium quibusdam corrupti quis?
                Natus doloremque illum commodi unde nostrum expedita
                tempora sapiente magnam asperiores, placeat dolorum vitae repellendus possimus ut,
            </p>
            <div>
                <h4>{{count}} Requests in total</h4>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>

        <div class="allrequests">

            {% for post in requests %}
                <div>
                    <!-- request -->
                    <h4>{{post.name}}  the request id is : {{post.id}} posted <strong>{{post.posted}}</strong></h4>
                    <p>--{{post.text}}</p> 


                    
                    <!--comment -->
                    <h5>Comments</h5>
                    <p>{{post.comments.all}}</p>
                    

                    <!-- comment input -->
                    <a href="{% url 'commentform' post.id  %}">
                        <h3>Add Comment</h3>
                    </a> 
                   
                </div>
            
                <hr>    
            {% endfor %}

        </div> 
    
    {% endblock content %}
```

pls if you can also give me any other tips i would highly appreciate it.
thanks

Comment: There should be something like a many to many relationship between comment and post, which is appropriate than a foreign key, IMO

Comment: So you think I should change Foreignkey to manytomany

Comment: Yes, I mean there should be a foreign key of course, but you must also link comment to the post in a way right? So for that, you could choose M2M

Answer (score 0):

Here you have set relation between them:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    request = models.ForeignKey('sunu_app.Post', ...)
    ...
```

So while you create new `Comment` object, you need to pass `Post` id or whole object to field `request` (I strongly recommend naming it `post` instead of `request`):

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
comment = Comment.objects.create(    # use round parenthesis
    request = post,
)
```

Comment: Yes I already set a relation

Comment: Are you sure the id=1

Comment: It's not direct solution. I just showed you how to create new `Comment` object with adequate relation with `Post`.